# using JList with Vector not printing anything

Tags: java, vector, jlist

I have the following class `ReviewPanel` in which i have created a JList and trying to populate it with Vector passed to it. the vector already has its values filled but when i add it to JList it doesn't shows anything.

following is my class

```
public class ReviewPanel extends JPanel


{
 private Vector bookList;
 private JList jl;
 private JRadioButton poor,fair,avg,good,exlnt;
 private JButton jb;


public ReviewPanel(Vector bookList)
 {

     this.bookList = bookList;
     jl = new JList<String>(this.bookList); 
     String tmp=null;

        for(int i=0;i<bookList.size();i++){
             tmp = tmp + bookList.get(i) + "\n"; 
                System.out.println(tmp); //here it is showing the values in booklist vector
        }   

        add(jl);
        ButtonGroup bg =new ButtonGroup();
        poor = new JRadioButton("1 Poor");
        fair = new JRadioButton("2 Fair");
        avg = new JRadioButton("3 Average");
        good = new JRadioButton("4 Good");
        exlnt = new JRadioButton("5 Excellent");
        bg.add(poor);  
        bg.add(fair);
        bg.add(avg);
        bg.add(good);
        bg.add(exlnt);
        add(poor);
        add(fair);
        add(avg);
        add(good);
        add(exlnt);
        jb = new JButton("Submit Review");
        add(jb);

  }
  //more code

}
```

below is the pic for what it looks like. even though i have added the Jlist already. it doesn't show anything 
[image: review panel image]

not savvy to jlist and vectors, any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be fully working here...

Comment: @Iootu : see the updated question. it isn't showing anything in review panel

Comment: It is running here on a JFrame, I believe you should update your question that this problem is applet related. Just now managed to run it as an applet as well...

Comment: @Iootu you can see i have extended JPanel class and created it what migh t be problem with this.

Comment: You might have thread issues, try to use `SwingUtilities` methods. Also, may I ask what class are you extending to create your `applet`?

Comment: created applet extending JApplet class

Comment: Then it must be probably a thread issue, as stated before, try to wrap your GUI creation code within a `SwingUtilities` method such as `invokeAndWait(...)`. Please let me know if you succeed at displaying the JList then.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have had simular issues with the `FlowLayout`, which is the default layout for a `JPanel`.

It sometimes does not show one of the items added (in my case it was often the last).

You can test if the use of your layout manager is your problem by starting you function with `setLayoutManager(null)`. This turns is off, which will place the elements on their default locations and sizes. If the `JList` does show this is your problem.

A very good example for your program is the [Button Demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ButtonDemoProject/src/components/ButtonDemo.java). This also shows the use of `SwingUtils` to make sure you create your program on the 'Event Dispatch Thread', which is required for all interaction with Swing objects.